# attribute before of css in class binding

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to color the content of paragraph element using a class binding on a given text:

the following code was a try but it is not working as expected

```
<p :class="getStyle"> hello world </p>
computed:{
    getStyle() {
     return document.body.style.background = "#8898";
    },
  },
```

Comment: @JaromandaX as said in the question I need to color the content of **<p>** which is **hello world**

Comment: @JaromandaX can the suggestion be addedcin answer

Comment: :style="'background-color: #8898''", or if you want dinamic:
----------------
<div....... :style="youColor" ....>
<script setup>
const youColor= ref(null)
function changeColor (){
  ... do there what you want ...
 youColor.value = ...
}
or it may be Computed method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you're dealing with `:class` you want `getStyle` (poorly named function by the way) to return a string which is some CSS class, that CSS class would assign a background (in your simple case) to whatever element contains that class

So this doesn't change
 hello world

This changes to something like

```
computed:{
    getStyle() {
     return "something";
    },
  },
```

and the style:

```
<style>
  .something {
    background: #8898;
  }
</style>
```

---

edit: using style instead

```
<p :style="getStyle"> hello world </p>
```

The computed changes to something like

```
computed:{
    getStyle() {
     return { background: "#8898" };
    },
  },
```

Comment: is it required to use `style block` ? i might need to use an array of string colors **["red", "yellow", "green"** so I access to it as following **colors[i]**

Comment: I prefer to get the style from script instead

Comment: @natalyren - you're the one that wants to use `:class` ... the only way a `class` can change the style of an element is through a `<style>` block! ... did you mean to use `:style=` instead?

Comment: @natalyren - have updated the code to show how you would use `:style=`

Comment: if there was multiple **<p> elements** it is possible to color them differently ? **red, yellow green..."** using for loop ?

Comment: you can change `getStyle()` to do whatever you like

Comment: I tried to do so but I always get the same color, the first one in the array (index 0) because of the return statement and if I remove the return no color

Comment: I can't see your mistake because I can't see your code

Comment: `let colors: ["red", "yellow", "green"]

  methods: {
    getStyle(param) {
      var rslt = param.map((p,i) => p.color = colors[i]);
      for( let i = 0;i < rslt.length; i++){
      var color = { background: rslt[i] };
     return color.background;
     }
    },
}`

Comment: that's it the code, can you figure out the mistake ? because that always color all **<p>** in red and I want them to be colored respectively red, yellow, green

Comment: what is `param`? why are you `return color.background;` ... you want to return an OBJECT ... like `return { background: rslt[i] }` you know, like my code ... `return { background: "#8898" };` ... read the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-inline-styles)

Comment: param is the array of **<p>** elements to loop over

Comment: ok I might have mistaken the return type. I edited it to return an object `return { background: rslt[i] }` yet this do not the issue. imo the issue is related to the return statement in for loop . **it iterates only once**

Comment: It's ok, I've found my mistake